# Determine the capacity of a died USB thumb drive from the output lsusb

Tags: debian, usb-flash-drive, lsusb

One of my USB thumb drives died: when I insert it into the USB socket in a Debian computer, the drive powers up and then powers down within a second or so.  The only diagnostics I was able to get during this second is this:

```
# lsusb -vvvvvvvvv -d 090c:2000

Bus 002 Device 027: ID 090c:2000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) USB DISK
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x090c Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.)
  idProduct          0x2000 
  bcdDevice           11.00
  iManufacturer           1 SMI Corporation
  iProduct                2 USB DISK
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x002c
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              504mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               8
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x0016
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000006
      BESL Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000c
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   2
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is High Speed (480Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           4 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat           4 micro seconds
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x000c
  (Bus Powered)
  U1 Enabled
  U2 Enabled
```

After the drive gets powered down again, I get no output.

I need to know the capacity of the drive. Based upon external information (purchase history), I logically deduced it must be either 256 GB or 512 GB. Yes, I also g**gled for “090C:2000” (and found someone else reporting 64 GB for vendor 090C and product 2000). The hull is [https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51qlBitw2FL.*AC_SL1001*.jpg](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51qlBitw2FL._AC_SL1001_.jpg) or [https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51tXG+oYzuL.*AC_SX679*.jpg](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51tXG+oYzuL._AC_SX679_.jpg), without extra information.  Breaking the hull would void the warranty for defects (not expried yet, provided I know which drive it is). Any idea which capacity the drive has or how to find it out?

`udisksctl monitor` gives me no capacity either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same story as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644696/usb-memory-stick-unmounts-and-vanishes who reports it is 256GB

This person has a similar USB stick and reports the problem could be fixed https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/can-not-mount-drive-4175432442/page2.html

Comment: That report says it's 256 GB, and another report https://usb-fix.blogspot.com/p/smi.html says it's 64 GB.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Reusing the PID is a bad idea. But some companies do it.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Yeah that 64gb number is in an old version of my answer. :-)

Comment: Looking into `journalctl -b` and `dmesg` was acutally a good idea — thanks!!! These reports say `[sdf] 491520000 512-byte logical blocks: (252 GB/234 GiB)` before reporting errors. As for fixing: I'm afraid I might need to go to year 2012 to apply their fix — and back then I don't think they had drives of this capacity.

Comment: @GeekestGeek https://www.kingston.com/netherlands/us/company/press/article/40500 A 256GB flashdrive.... in 2010!

Comment: Sure, and the price tag was not for a typical end consumer. (To compare, you even had the computers in 1980's – 1990's computing as fast as your smartphone today. But it was a top Cray worth of millions $$$ back then.)